# Session for single value data is getting from database and for double value data is not coming

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, session

This is my code

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Products where cast(ProductID as nvarchar(100)) in ('" + Session["Products"] + "')", con))
{
     con.Open();
     using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
          while (sdr.Read())
          {
               customers.Add(new ProductsData());
               customers[customers.Count - 1].ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ProductID"].ToString());
               customers[customers.Count - 1].CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["CategoryID"].ToString());
               customers[customers.Count - 1].Title = sdr["Title"].ToString();
               customers[customers.Count - 1].ThumbNail = sdr["ThumbNail"].ToString();
               customers[customers.Count - 1].IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IsActive"].ToString());
               customers[customers.Count - 1].FlashPath = sdr["FlashPath"].ToString();
               customers[customers.Count - 1].Price = Convert.ToDouble(sdr["Price"]);
               customers[customers.Count - 1].Description = sdr["Description"].ToString();
               //customers[customers.Count - 1].CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["customer_id"]);
               //customers[customers.Count - 1].FirstName = sdr["firstname"].ToString();
               //customers[customers.Count - 1].LastName = sdr["lastname"].ToString();
          }
      con.Close();
      //return customers;
   }
}
```

Here when `Session["Products"]` value is **1** ,Data is coming and is entering in to while loop

When `Session["Products"]` value is **1,2** ,while loop is not entering what is my problem with this code  Plz can u suggest me

Session data declaration Updated

```
 protected void chkFocusArea_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
        //update label count if checkbox is checked
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)cb.NamingContainer;
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)item;

        string code = productslist.DataKeys[dataItem.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString();
        //Header h1 = (Header)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/Header.ascx");

        //CitandPrototype.UserControls.Header h1 = new UserControls.Header();
        //Label mylabel = new Label();
        //mylabel=(Label)h1.FindControl("lblitems");


        string mylabel = ((Label)((this.Master).FindControl("Header")).FindControl("lblitems")).Text;

        string mylabelitems = ((HiddenField)((this.Master).FindControl("Header")).FindControl("lblitemshidden")).Value;

        if (!mylabelitems.Contains(code))

            if (mylabel.Length == 0)
        {
           // mylabelitems += "," + code;
            mylabelitems = code;
        }
        else
        {
           // mylabelitems = code;
            mylabelitems += ","+code;
        }

        int.TryParse(mylabel, out x);

        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (x > 0)
                x -= 1;
            else
                x = 0;

            mylabelitems=mylabelitems.Replace(code, string.Empty);

        }
        ((Label)((this.Master).FindControl("Header")).FindControl("lblitems")).Text =x.ToString();
        ((HiddenField)((this.Master).FindControl("Header")).FindControl("lblitemshidden")).Value = mylabelitems.Trim();
        Session["ProductCount"] = x.ToString();
        Session["Products"] = mylabelitems.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because of this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Products where cast(ProductID as nvarchar(100)) in ('" + Session["Products"] + "')", con))
```

your final query is becoming:

```
select * from Products where cast(ProductID as nvarchar(100)) in ('1,2')
```

and should be:

```
select * from Products where cast(ProductID as nvarchar(100)) in ('1','2')
```

or

```
select * from Products where ProductID  in (1,2)
```

try to write as:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Products where ProductID  in (" + Session['Products'] + ")", con))
```

**EDIT:**

```
 mylabelitems=mylabelitems.Replace(","+code, string.Empty);
```

Comment: How to get this type ('1','2') in my session plz can u tell me

Comment: see at last i have mentioned

Comment: Thanks i got it ,,,but first i selected 5 checkboxes ,i got the data ,when i uncheck the 3 checkboxes am getting error "," :Incorrect syntax near ','.using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())

Comment: @Kailas what is value of session becoming in that case?

Comment: Based on the check box selection session["Products"] will update , when i uncheck am getting error

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')'. after uncheck ,Incorrect syntax near ','.At this position using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())

Comment: After uncheck session value is Session["Products"]="1,"  .That comma after 1 is not going this is the issue

Comment: will u post the code where u have assigning the values to session?

Comment: @Kailas wait i m checking

Comment: @Kailas again made small edit in condtiotion...check and tell quickly

Comment: code<>null or code.toString()<>"" here am getting lot of things to be expected

Comment: I think when we uncheck Ex:1,2 .....Ex:1, this comma we have to remove when we uncheck

Comment: Thanq u very much for ur valuble time